# tokenByIndex method don't work for contract, how could I get Token Id

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, nft

I use opensea.io for create nft tokens.
I want create 100 tokens and then create redeem  mechanism on my site (allow download music).
I created contract using: "?enable_supply=true" https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xee45b41d1ac24e9a620169994deb22739f64f231

But I can't get Token Id:

```
contract.methods.tokenByIndex(walletAddress, 0).call()
```

seems theres no method tokenByIndex.
I need know  TokenId for each  item, it for my redeem  mechanism.
Could I do it with this  contract or I need use custom contract?

Comment: From the source code it seems they implement [EIP 1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155). That EIP recommends using events to track token IDs.